# Why doesn't doOnNext() get called?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, reactivex

Neither onNext() nor onCompleted() get called for my subscriber below.  I've tried implementing the subscriber via doOnNext()/doOnTerminate().  I also tried doAfterTerminate().  I've also tried explicitly defining a subscriber and neither onNext() nor onCompleted() got called for it.

According to [RxJS reduce doesn't continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595954/rxjs-reduce-doesnt-continue), it's the reduce() that's not terminating so I tried adding the take(1) but that didn't work.  In the same stackoverflow question someone said the problem might be my stream never closes.  Aside from take(1), maybe there is some other way I should close the stream, but I don't understand ReactiveX well enough yet.

According to [Why is OnComplete not called in this code? (RxAndroid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316694/why-is-oncomplete-not-called-in-this-code-rxandroid?rq=1), it could be that the original stream in the series doesn't terminate.  But I don't see why that would matter if I'm calling take(1) which I think is supposed to emit a termination signal.

Basically, why doesn't the following line get executed?

```
System.out.println("doOnNext map.size()=" + map.size());
```

Even though the following line of code gets executed 98 times:

```
map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

**JsonObjectObservableRequest.java**

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
...
public class JsonObjectObservableRequest {

    public JsonObjectObservableRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject request) {
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, request, getResponseListener(),     getResponseErrorListener());
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> getResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                publishSubject.onNext(Observable.just(response));
            }
        };
    }

    private Response.ErrorListener getResponseErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Observable<JSONObject> myError = Observable.error(error);
                publishSubject.onNext(myError);
            }
        };
    }

    public JsonObjectRequest getJsonObjectRequest() {
        return jsonObjectRequest;
    }

    public Observable<JSONObject> getObservable() {
    return publishSubject.flatMap(new Func1<Observable<JSONObject>, Observable<    JSONObject>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<JSONObject> call(Observable<JSONObject> jsonObjectObservable) {
                return jsonObjectObservable;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**JsonObjectObservableRequest calling code**

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
...
    JsonObjectObservableRequest jsonObjectObservableRequest = new JsonObjectObservableRequest(Request.Method.GET, idURLString, null, keyId, key);
    Observable<JSONObject> jsonObjectObservable = jsonObjectObservableRequest.getObservable();

    jsonObjectObservable
            .map(json -> {
                try {
                    return NetworkAccountIdDatasource.parseIdJSON(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
            .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>("Name of " + s, "short id for " + s.substring(4)))
            .reduce(new HashMap<String, String>(), (map, e) -> {
                map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                return map;
            })
            .take(1)
            .doOnNext(map -> {
                System.out.println("doOnNext map.size()=" + map.size());
            })
            .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                System.out.println("doOnTerminate");
            })
            .subscribe();

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.add(jsonObjectObservableRequest.getJsonObjectRequest());
```

Comment: why you still using volley, retrofit2 is the new way!

Comment: Thank you @Remario .  How do you know that?

Comment: well for one, its less verbose, faster(okHttp3) and uses java annotation processor. I mean every android developer pretty much switch by now.

Comment: do read up on it, you will love it!

Comment: Better reason is that Retrofit2 has direct support for a call adapter that provides Observable directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the doOnTerminate() and doOnNext() to be called.  It was to place the take(1) statement higher up in the stream processing.  I got this idea based on the comment from @yosriz .  I wish I understood why this fixed the problem, but I don't because I thought a termination signal would just get propagated through, but I guess there is a lot more I need to learn about ReactiveX / reactive functional programming / etc..

**JsonObjectObservableRequest calling code**

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
...
    JsonObjectObservableRequest jsonObjectObservableRequest = new JsonObjectObservableRequest(Request.Method.GET, idURLString, null, keyId, key);
    Observable<JSONObject> jsonObjectObservable = jsonObjectObservableRequest.getObservable();

jsonObjectObservable
        .map(json -> {
            try {
                return NetworkAccountIdDatasource.parseIdJSON(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        })
        .take(1) // SOLUTION: MOVED THIS UP FROM BELOW reduce()
        .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
        .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>("Name of " + s, "short id for " + s.substring(4)))
        .reduce(new HashMap<String, String>(), (map, e) -> {
            map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            return map;
        })
        // .take(1) // SOLUTION: MOVE THIS ABOVE flatMapIterable() 
        .doOnNext(map -> {
            System.out.println("doOnNext map.size()=" + map.size());
        })
        .doOnTerminate(() -> {
            System.out.println("doOnTerminate");
        })
        .subscribe();

final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
queue.add(jsonObjectObservableRequest.getJsonObjectRequest());
```

Furthermore, it works also if I put take(1) as the very first operation, before the first map() operation (the one that calls parseIdJSON()).  However, if I put take(1) as the operation just before reduce(), it only partially works; the good thing is doOnNext() gets called but the bad thing is the map.size() is always 1 when it should be 98 for my data set.

Comment: did you read thoroughly my answer? you're not calling onCompleted at the JsonObjectObservableRequest, you're Observable is never ends (complete) = reduce cannot work (simply because it never get completion event)

Answer (score 1):

You identified correctly the problem, you're not calling `onCompleted()` on the source network `Observable` (at the `JsonObjectObservableRequest` class), while the `take(1)` is not helpful either because you put it **before** the `reduce`.
As you were probably understood, reduce must operate on `Observable` with finite number of emissions, as it's emit the accumulated item when all items have been emitted and thus it's relies on the `onCompleted()` event to know when the observed stream has end.

- I think that in your case, the best thing is to change the way `JsonObjectObservableRequest` operates, you don't need a `Subject` for this, you can use creation methods to wrap a callback (you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152595/rx-java-android-how-to-convert-this-callback-block-to-observer/43164771#43164771), and read more about bridging between callback world to RxJava [here](https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/converting-callback-async-calls-to-rxjava-ebc68bde5831).
- Moreover, you don't need the emit an `Observable` of something and then `flatmap` it to items, you can simply emit the item with `onNext()` and emit an error with `onError()`, actually you're hiding the errors and converting them to an emission, this might make it harder to handle errors down the stream.
- You should call`onCompleted()` at `onResponse()` after you call `onNext()` to signal the completion. and in the case of error, signaling `onError` will notify termination of the stream.
- Another concern is canceling the request which seems not handled in this way, you can read the sources up to see how it can be done when wrapping callbacl call.